# How to Upload Multipart That Exceed Size Limit?

Tags: java, resize, size, multipart

I have backend API that suppose to upload Multipart file, but when the file size exceed limit it shows error 500 like this :

```
message:Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/marketplace] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (10510555) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)] with root cause
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (10510555) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)
```

so, the current solution is changing my application.yml for multipart setting to something like this :

```
http:
multipart:
  max-file-size: -1
  max-request-size: -1
```

And it works great, but
turns out I'm not allowed to change this application.yml
My other solution was to change Frontend file size checking and resize but turns out I also only allowed to change the backend.

Question :
Is there any other way  so I can change the multipart request size before it hits app ?

Comment: *but turns out I'm not allowed to change this application.yml* - what does this mean?

Comment: its a group project, I can't change the application.yml no matter what

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution, I don't have to change my application.yml

I added this line of code at my app.java

```
@Bean
    MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize(50000000);
        factory.setMaxRequestSize(50000000);
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }
```

And It works great, you can edit the filesize.
Hope this can help anyone else that has the same problem